# How to initialize final properties in class constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to initialize a field by other field
for example server URL and image URL should be also final

```
class Config {
  final bool isDev = EnvironmentConfig.app_env == "development";
  final bool isProd = EnvironmentConfig.app_env == "production";
  final bool isQA = EnvironmentConfig.app_env == "qa";
  String localHost = Platform.isAndroid ? "10.0.2.2" : "localHost";

  String serverUrl;
  String imageUrl;

  Config() {
    if (this.isDev) {
      this.serverUrl = "http://$localHost:3000";
    } else if (this.isProd) {
      this.serverUrl = "";
    } else if (this.isQA) {
      this.serverUrl = "";
    } else {
      print("error: " + EnvironmentConfig.app_env);
    }
    this.imageUrl = this.serverUrl + "/api/files/image/";
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a satisfying answer to this question?

Comment: declarations must be initialized so i don't think what i wanted to accomplish is possible.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you have should work just fine (provided that `EnvironmentConfig.app_env` is accessing a static variable). However, if you want to do the more traditional way of make final variables, take this route:

```
class Config {
  final bool isDev;
  final bool isProd;
  final bool isQA;
  
  // Other variables
  Config(this.isDev, this.isProd, this.isQA) {
    // Other code
  }
}
```

But why not have a final `env` variable and use getters for `isDev`, `isProd`, and `isQa`? Note: you could also pass in `env` to the constructor as I showed above.

```
class Config {
  final String env = EnvironmentConfig.app_env;
  bool get isDev => env == "development";
  bool get isProd => env == "production";
  bool get isQA => env == "qa";
  String localHost = Platform.isAndroid ? "10.0.2.2" : "localHost";

  String serverUrl;
  String imageUrl;

  Config() {
    if (this.isDev) {
      this.serverUrl = "http://$localHost:3000";
    } else if (this.isProd) {
      this.serverUrl = "";
    } else if (this.isQA) {
      this.serverUrl = "";
    } else {
      print("error: " + env);
    }
    this.imageUrl = this.serverUrl + "/api/files/image/";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
 class _A {
      _A(bool limitPages, int pagesToDisplay)
      final int pagesToDisplay;
      final bool limitPages;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: i want to get the value by conditions not just give him default value in the constructor. i cant make condition outside of the constructor maybe if it is Ternary conditions but i prefer it wont be.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value inside Contructor of your class.

```
   class YourClass {
          YourClass ({bool a=true, String b= "example",});
          final bool a;
          final String b;
    
        }
```

- Later, you can call: `var instance = YourClass();` it means  instance have default value: a=true and b='example'.
- If you want change value: `var otherInstance = YourClass(a:false,b:"newValue");`

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: I want to get the value by conditions not just give him default value in the constructor. i cant make condition outside of the constructor maybe if it is Ternary conditions but i prefer it wont be.